# How to randomise vertex position along an axis

Tags: mesh

In Edit Mode I click on Randomize under Mesh Tools to randomise the position of vertices on a mesh:

[image]

What I've noticed is that this randomises the position on all axes. Is there any way to do the same randomisation of vertices but constraining it to one or more axes (locally or globally)? A mockup of the desired output is shown below in which the vertices are randomised along the global x axis.

[image]

Comment: there is a [free addon](https://www.artstation.com/a/35078839) that may be handy for you.
It allows to apply a random offset to the selected vertices along the desired axis and within a defined range.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use *Proportional Editing* set to a random falloff.

Basically, select the vertices you want affected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, to invert the selection, and then <kbd>H</kbd> to hide those vertices. Now, select a vertex of the ones left, press <kbd>O</kbd>, to turn *Proportional Editing* on, and, in the 3D view header, set the falloff to *random*:

[image: Random falloff]

Then, press <kbd>G</kbd>, to move, followed by one of <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>, either once or twice, to limit to the axis you want. Now, use the scroll wheel to enlarge the affected area so that all the vertices are affected and move the mouse until you get the results you want.
Then, press  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show all hidden vertices again.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be quite what you're looking for, but in the sculpting tab I stumbled across the *Mesh Filter*. It appears to affect *all* vertices - there's probably a way to limit this, but I haven't discovered it yet (I'm a Blender beginner).

Access it by first selecting the object you want to edit. Then:

1. Click the "Sculpting" tab at the top of the screen
2. In the left-hand toolbox choose the blue *Mesh Filter* option
3. In the right-hand toolbox choose which axis or axes you want to deform on (shift + click to select multiple axes; selected axes are highlighted in blue)
4. Finally, click and drag over the mesh in the left/right directions to control how much deformation you want to apply.

[image: (see instructions above)]

*(Running Blender 2.83 on Ubuntu Linux 20.10)*

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Mesh > Transform > Randomize

Comment: This doesn't provide options to randomise along a specific axis

Comment: Well if they're supposed to stay aligned, you can then just do `S Z 0` or `S Y 0` to unscale them

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any tool to achieve that directly under edit mode. You could however achieve similar results with a displace modifier.
If I am not mistaken, displace can move vertex along the local surface normal, then use some texture to simulate randomization.

Edit: Alternatively if you want to move all verts in a single direction you could use the *Proportional Edit* with *Random* editing fallout